# Unity remove logo in splash screen

Tags: unity, legal, copyright, publishing, trademark

Heavily related to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/72087/81922), as of now, [Unity's TOS](https://unity3d.com/legal/terms-of-service) has changed dramatically. And searching in the TOS, it looks like I'm allowed to remove the Unity logo in my exported game. Looking at Section 4.1, it still retains:

> You will not remove, alter or obscure any copyright, trademark,
>   service mark or other proprietary rights notices incorporated in or
>   accompanying the Services.

However looking at how "Services" is defined in the first paragraph of the TOS:

> Unity Technologies ApS (“Unity”, “our” or “we”) provides
>   game-development and related software (the “Software”),
>   development-related services (like Unity Analytics (“Developer
>   Services”)), and various Unity communities (like Unity Answers and and
>   the Made with Unity Platform (“Communities”)), provided through or in
>   connection with our website, accessible at unity3d.com or unity.com
>   (collectively, the “Site”). Except to the extent you and Unity have
>   executed a separate agreement, these terms and conditions exclusively
>   govern your access to and use of the Software, Developer Services,
>   Communities and Site (collectively, the “Services”)

It does not seem to include the exported game itself. And even if Section 4.1 says "accompanying the services", I assume it still wouldn't include the game as the game does not need to accompany them. Otherwise it would be illegal to remove the logo from the splash screen from a game made in Unity Pro since the TOS applies to all tiers of Unity. Furthermore, I haven't found anywhere that says you can't modify or hack into the produced executables (I even looked [in here](https://unity3d.com/legal/terms-of-service/software) which contains another part of the TOS). Does this mean I can remove the logo from the splash screen no matter what Unity tier (personal, plus or pro) I'm using?

(My aim is to actually move it to a dedicated credits section accessible from the title screen of the game rather than having it appear in the splash screen. Players of the game will still know that it's made in Unity.)

Comment: if they did'n want you to remove it then they wouldn't give you the ability to. as long as you have a legitimate licence you can alter your end game as much as unity allows it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The exported game still includes the Unity engine Software.
2. Unity are the ones that should be contacted with request for clarifications and executing a separate agreement that would let you move the logo.
3. Consult a lawyer.

Answer (score 6):

The option to remove the Unity logo from the splash screen is one of the perks of the paid tiers (Plus and Pro).

So the simple answer is: **pay for Unity**, and you can use the built-in features to turn off the logo.

Comment: Firstly not everyone has the money to do so, especially when making a game that's meant to be free in the first place. Secondly, I would rather have some proof, such as quotes from the TOS that says I can or can't do certain things.

Comment: If you don't have the budget to pay for Unity, then you need to respect the limitations of the free version the Unity developers have generously provided to us all. You have the quotation you're asking for in the question itself: "you will not remove...any copyright, trademark, service mark..." and yes, the Unity engine binaries in a compiled build are part of "the Software" as Stephane Hockenhull points out.